# Error al insertar xml con curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

Hola buenas tardes hice una conexión a un CRM con Postman para poder insertar unos datos fijos y si se insertan los datos, jale el código Curl de postman a PHP y sigue funcionando, pero intente simplificar el código para no meter los caracteres extraños y es ahí cuando no me inserta los datos al CRM, podrían apoyarme a saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal. Les comparto mi código.

> Código funcional de Postman (si inserta)

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write?authtoken=010100110101&scope=creatorapi&zc_ownername=nombre&XMLString=%3CZohoCreator%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Capplicationlist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Capplication%20name='zoho-cdr'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cformlist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20name='Formulario_Carga_Inicial'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cadd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfield%20name='ID_CDR'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvalue%3E1213%3C/value%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/field%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfield%20name='RFC_CRM'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvalue%3Edede%3C/value%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/field%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/add%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cadd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfield%20name='ID_CDR'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvalue%3E1415%3C/value%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/field%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfield%20name='RFC_CRM'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvalue%3Efefe%3C/value%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/field%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/add%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/form%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/formlist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/application%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/applicationlist%3E%0A%3C/ZohoCreator%3E",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/xml",
    "Cookie: 442b5845d7=f0ca98fc689b02462286b17d3e437fd5; zccpn=92167dc4-975f-4cab-89e4-3fc88eeb3c03; _zcsr_tmp=92167dc4-975f-4cab-89e4-3fc88eeb3c03; a4c02fa025=bf0bdc2fa4f4c1d32cc406c8ae7a93bf; JSESSIONID=8BD49C32B1C7BF25065E45DFE1AAB016"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

> Código que simplifique no funcional (no inserta)

```
$data_xml = "<ZohoCreator>
                      <applicationlist>
                          <application name='zoho-cdr'>
                              <formlist>
                                  <form name='Formulario_Carga_Inicial'>
                                      <add>
                                          <field name='ID_CDR'>
                                              <value>1213</value>
                                          </field>
                                          <field name='RFC_CRM'>
                                              <value>dede</value>
                                          </field>
                                      </add>
                                      <add>
                                          <field name='ID_CDR'>
                                              <value>1415</value>
                                          </field>
                                          <field name='RFC_CRM'>
                                              <value>fefe</value>
                                          </field>
                                      </add>
                                  </form>
                              </formlist>
                          </application>
                      </applicationlist>
                  </ZohoCreator>";

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ['authtoken' => '10101010', 'scope' => 'creatorapi', 'zc_ownername' => 'nombre', 'XMLString' => $data_xml],
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/xml",
        "Cookie: 442b5845d7=f0ca98fc689b02462286b17d3e437fd5; zccpn=92167dc4-975f-4cab-89e4-3fc88eeb3c03; _zcsr_tmp=92167dc4-975f-4cab-89e4-3fc88eeb3c03; a4c02fa025=bf0bdc2fa4f4c1d32cc406c8ae7a93bf; JSESSIONID=346922BC9296563FFE3A816A073F2EBE"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

> Error

***{"code":2945,"message":"LESS_THAN_MIN_OCCURANCE"}***

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema y/o error en concreto? No está explicado con claridad en la pregunta.

Comment: Listo ya coloque el error que me manda

Comment: El problema no creo que sea cURL, sino que es un problema del servicio o API que estás consultando. Revisa [este hilo de su soporte técnico](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/zoho-creator-xml-rpc-api-error-code-2945-invalid-ticket), creo que vas a tener que contactar con ellos. El problema aquí no es cURL.

Comment: Es que si hace el insert de la primera forma, pero cuando lo adapto no pero según yo esta todo bien verdad?

Comment: Del lado de cURL puede que esté todo bien, si no lo está, te lo dirá si estableces un control de errores adecuado. Pero el hecho de que el cURL esté bien no significa que todo esté bien, puede haber algo mal en el servicio que rechace la petición y eso tendrás que resolverlo a nivel del servicio/API, pues no tiene que ver con cURL.

Comment: podrías mandarme un ejemplo de un control de errores por favor

Comment: coloque lo siguiente if ($response === false)
      {
          print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
      }

Comment: [Revisa el **Ejemplo 1** del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-error.php). La llamada a `curl_exec()` devuelve `false` cuando hay un fallo, puedes evaluar esa llamada y mostrar el error mediante `curl_error()`.

Comment: En tu caso sería algo así: `if($response = curl_exec($curl)) { var_dump($response); //o echo según el caso, puse var_dump para depurar } else { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl); }`

Comment: si como el ejemplo que mande verdad? y no esta entrando al if

Comment: entro al if y me manda el siguiente error string(50) "{"code":2945,"message":"LESS_THAN_MIN_OCCURANCE"}

Comment: Correcto, es justo lo que te dije antes: no es un error de cURL, sino de la API o servicio web que estás consultando. El mismo responde un JSON correcto para cURL, pero no para los datos que estás pidiendo, porque allí (en la API), está ocurriendo un error. No está aceptando las credenciales que estás mandando o algo sucede. El `LESS_THAN_MIN_OCCURANCE` puede dar una pista de ese error, pero debes consultar con ellos, para saber por qué ocurre y cómo resolverlo.

Comment: Según [la doc de la API](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/creator-error-codes.html) el código de error `2945` ocurre cuando mandas un ticket inválido.

Comment: pero es el mismo que estoy utilizando con el que si hace el insert eso es lo que se me hace extraño.

Comment: No sé, quizá ellos requieran otro tipo de parámetro cuando se trata de un XML.